# Plotly Express prevent text values from appearing in hover template

Tags: plotly, mousehover, plotly.js, plotly-express

How do I prevent the text values passed as `text=df.petal_width.values` in the example below from showing up in the hover tooltip? They should only display as annotations directly on the plot.

[image: plot]

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter(
    df,
    x="sepal_length",
    y="sepal_width",
    color="species",
    text=df.petal_width.values,
)

fig.show()
```

To be clear, I know I could pass `text=df.petal_width` and the tooltip value would not be called `text` but `petal_width`. This is not what I want. I want it gone entirely. Only way I found so far is ugly:

```py
hov_temp = [
    x for x in fig.data[0].hovertemplate.split("<br>") if not x.startswith("text")
]
fig.data[0].hovertemplate = "<br>".join(hov_temp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a dict with labels to `hover_data` and `text=df.petal_width`:

```
labels = {'species':True,'sepal_length':True,'sepal_width':True,'petal_length':False,'petal_width':False}
fig = px.scatter(df,x='sepal_length',y='sepal_width',color='species',text=df.petal_width,hover_data=labels)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, looks like just `labels = {'petal_width': False}` is enough.

Comment: `text` can also be a column name. So `col='petal_width'` and `px.scatter(...,text=col,hover_data={col:False})` also works